# Is there a way to get index in for / for_each loop in terraform?

Tags: loops, foreach, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have multiple aws_launch_configurations created. Now i need to create ASG by passing the output values of already created aws_launch_configurations. The outputs are in an array format:

```
lc_name = ["A", "B"]
autoscale_spec = [{"name":"1"}, {"name":2"}]


resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "test" {
for_each = { for spec in var.autoscale_spec:  spec.name => spec }
 launch_configuration = var.lc_name[index]
}
```

I want to get the index of autoscale_spec loop so that i can refer it to get lc_name

Comment: You should not do that, correlating data based on the index is never a good idea. Instead have proper mappings that correlate `lc_name` and `autoscale_spec`.

Comment: I have around 10 LC 's getting created && the LC name gets suffixed with timestamp. Hence going with this approach.. I need to dynamically refer from outputs array

Comment: It worked!!! thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

This solution worked for me -->

```
lc_name = ["A", "B"]
autoscale_spec = [{"name":"1"}, {"name":2"}]


resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "test" {
for_each = { for spec in var.autoscale_spec:  index(var.autoscale_spec, spec) => spec }
 launch_configuration = var.lc_name[each.key]
}
```

Thanks for the help.